# Undefined symbols: Showing Recent Issues Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

Multiple -
Showing Recent Issues
Ignoring file '...': tapi error: missing required architecture x86_64 in file

How to reproduce:

1. Create an empty project.
2. pod init
3. pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
   pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
   pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
   pod 'GoogleMLKit/Translate', '3.2.0'
4. pod install
5. Run on simulator.

How to fix it?

Found solution - adding -ld64 to Other Linker Flags.